# I don't know why length is +1 than real in textfile

Tags: c, split, c-strings, strtok, strlen

The following code check the longest word in a string.

```
char *fp2 = strtok(str, " .");

if (fp2 == NULL) {
    if(strlen(str) >= length) {
        length = strlen(str);
    }
}  else if (fp2 != NULL) {
    while (fp2 != NULL) {
        if (strlen(fp2) >= length) {
            length = strlen(fp2);
        }
        fp2 = strtok(NULL, " .");
    }
}
```

`str` is textfile and the length is variable.

but if textfile is like this
`"aa\na "`
it release 3 not 2.

Why is this release +1 than real? I don't know.....

Comment: "aa a " looks like a length of 5 to me.

Comment: need to see complete runnable program please.

Comment: How about you print the strings (with some start and end indicators, to catch whitespaces) and see yourself?

Comment: Perhaps you also want the newline to act as a separator? Like this: `char *fp2 = strtok(str, "\n .");`

Comment: @C baby    In may opinion this substring "aa\na" contains neither 2 nor 3 but 4 characters.:)

Comment: And I put \n as the comment above and solved it. I'm stupid for not thinking about this. Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: @Oka And what? The substring is separated by the space character.

Comment: So was the actual string `"aa\n a"`?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Ah, I missed "sub" in your comment.

Comment: Reading text file one char at a time (to find longest word) will be efficient that this `strtok()` & `strlen()` combo; it'll become obvious for large text files.

Answer (score 0):

the asnwer should be 4

```
 "aa\na a"
  12 34
```

this code

```
int main() {
    char str[] = "aa\na a";
    char* fp2 = strtok(str, " .");
    int length = 0;
    if (fp2 == NULL) {
        if (strlen(str) >= length) {
            length = strlen(str);
        }
    }
    else if (fp2 != NULL) {
        while (fp2 != NULL) {
            if (strlen(fp2) >= length) {
                length = strlen(fp2);
            }
            fp2 = strtok(NULL, " .");
        }
    }
    printf("length = %d\n", length);
}
```

produces

```
length = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters the if statement is redundant. If the string `str` does not contain any character except the characters specified as delimiters then you will get in any case the value of `length` equal to `0` without using the if statement.

```
if (fp2 == NULL) {
    if(strlen(str) >= length) {
        length = strlen(str);
    }
```

That is the string does not contain a word.

Also in this if statement

```
    if (strlen(fp2) >= length) {
```

it is better to use the operator `>` instead of the operator `>=`

```
    if (strlen(fp2) > length) {
```

And you should avoid redundant calls of `strlen`.

The code can look simpler as for example the following way

```
size_t length = 0;
char *fp2 = strtok(str, " .");

while (fp2 != NULL) {
    size_t n = strlen( fp2 );  
    if ( length  < n ) {
        length = n;
    }
    fp2 = strtok(NULL, " .");
}
```

For the string looked like `"aa\na "` the maximum substring contains 4 characters `"aa\na"`. To exclude the new line character `'\n'` you need to include it in the set of delimiters.

In general it is much better to use functions `strspn` and `strcspn` instead of `strtok` without changing the source string.